# How to evaluate a dataframe containing power expressions in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Below is the code,

I tried to use df.eval(), but the output was unexpected as shown below,
Please help!

```
import pandas as pd
data = [1,2,2^0,2^6,5]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df.eval(data))
```

Output: [1 2 2 4 5]
Expected Output : [1 2 1 64 5]

EDIT:

The proposed solution works perfectly for csv file, but fails when excel file is parsed.
Below is the code:

```
arrowToPower = lambda x : eval(x.replace('^', '**'))
df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', decimal=',', 
converters={'C2': arrowToPower})



output: [['geeky' '2^10']
 ['abs' 2]
 ['sdf' '2^2']]
```

Answer (score 0):

In *Python*, the *power* operator is written as `**` (not `^`).

`^` is *XOR* operator.

So probably you should replace `^` with `**`.

## Edit following your comment

I suppose that you want the source numbers to read as "true"
numbers (either integer or float), not at their text representation.

From your question I also know that you want to change e.g. `2^0` to the
intermediate value of `2**0` and keep it also as a number (in this
case `1`).

I didn't manage to prepare a source *.xlsx* file (despite my
efforts, my Jupiter kept complaining that it was *not UTF-8 encoded*),
so I prepared an example with reading from *.csv* file instead.

So let's start from source *.csv* file:

```
C1;C2;C3;C4;C5;C6;C7;C8
geeky;0;1,9921875;0;2^0;0;T_U8;0
xyz;0;3,2044218;1;3^4;3;T_X2;4
```

The first thing to note is that the field separator is `;`
(not a comma). This is required because floating point numbers
have a comma (instead of a dot) between integer and fractional
part.

`C5` column contains `2^0` and `3^4`, which are to be converted
to the intermediate shape of `2**0` and `3**4` and finally to
`1` and `81`.

To do the above conversion I wrote a function:

```
arrowToPower = lambda x : eval(x.replace('^', '**'))
```

Then reading of a DataFrame can be performed as:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Input.csv', sep=';', decimal=',', converters={'C5': arrowToPower})
```

The points to note are as follows:

- `Input.csv` is the input file name.
- `sep=';'` specifies the column separator.
- `decimal=','` specifies what separates integer and fractional
  part.
- `converters={'C5': arrowToPower}` assigns a converter function to
  `C5` column.

When you print the `df`, the result is:

```
      C1  C2        C3  C4  C5  C6    C7  C8
0  geeky   0  1.992188   0   1   0  T_U8   0
1    xyz   0  3.204422   1  81   3  T_X2   4
```

To read from an *Excel* file, you should change `read_csv` to `read_excel`,
change the file name and drop `sep` parameter.

If you have more columns with `^` instead of `**`, assign the converter also
to these columns.

## Edit concerning reading Excel file

Finally I succeeded in writing such an Excel file, which could be read
by `read_excel`.

[image]

Then I executed:

```
df2 = pd.read_excel('Input.xlsx', converters={'C5': arrowToPower})
```

and got the proper result.

Values read into `C5` column were `1` and `81`, so `arrowToPower` converter
has definitely been called.

Note that the first row of the Excel file contains column names
and following rows - the actual data.
In case of Excel files the comma as separator between decimal and fractional
parts is only a presentation issue and under the hood `read_excel` reads
internal content. This is why *decimal* parameter is not needed here.

So I still think that your input (Excel) file is in some respect "wrong",
maybe it does not contain column names in the first row.

Comment: Thanks, that worked!! Now I have one more scenario wherein Im reading the excel and storing the rows into a dataframe, here arises the problem.                                                                  Consider the below dataframe
 ['geeky' '0' '1,9921875' '0' '2^0' '0' 'T_U8' '0']                                                               
 The resultant dataframe i need is:                                                                                        ['geeky' '0' '1,9921875' '0' '1' '0' 'T_U8' '0']             Will I be able to get that?

Comment: Apparently the converter has not been called for *C2* column.
Maybe the reason is that the column in question has different name.
Check whether the first row of your file contains column names.
Alternative: If the input file has no column names (in the initial row),
you can specify them with *names* parameter and *header=None*.
Another hint: As I see from your output, you included the printout
for *df.values* (it does not contain column names). Execute *print(df)*
and include its output instead, so that column names were also present.